# Custom Hadoop Configuration for Spark from Python (PySpark)?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I have `Python`-based script which should be run on `Apache Spark` cluster.

I have `Hadoop` `MapReduce` `InputFormat` as a data source for `RDD`. Here is no problem.

The problem is I'd like to construct custom `Hadoop` `Configuration` with additional resource files loaded and attributes set. Intention is to use modified `Configuration` inside `Python` `SparkContext`.

I can build `JVM` code which can construct and load needed `Hadoop` `Configuration`. How to attach it to `Python` using `PySpark`?

Does anybody know how all of this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this puzzle for my case when dropped requirement to modify `Configuration`online and just base on custom set of Hadoop configuration *.xml files.

At first I have written Java class which adds configuration of additional layers to default resources for `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`. It's static initialization appends Configuration default resoutces:

```
public class Configurator {

    static {

        // We initialize needed Hadoop configuration layers default configuration
        // by loading appropriate classes.

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to initialize HDFS configuartion layer.");
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to initialize YARN/MapReduce configuartion layer.");
        }

        // We do what actually HBase should: default HBase configuration
        // is added to default Hadoop resources.
        Configuration.addDefaultResource("hbase-default.xml");
        Configuration.addDefaultResource("hbase-site.xml");
    }

    // Just 'callable' handle.
    public void init() {
    }

}
```

So now if someone just loads my `Configurator` he or she has the following inftastructure configurations searched over class path: core, hdfs, MapReduce, YARN, HBase. Appropriate files are `core-default.xml`, `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-default.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `mapred-default.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`, `yarn-default.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, `hbase-default.xml`, `hbase-site.xml`. If I will need additional layers, no problem to extend.

`Configurator.init()` is provided just to have more trivial handle for class loading.

Now I need to extend Python Spark scripts with access to configurator during Spark context startup:

```
# Create minimal Spark context.
sc = SparkContext(appName="ScriptWithIntegratedConfig")

# It's critical to initialize configurator so any
# new org.apach.hadoop.Configuration object loads our resources.
sc._jvm.com.wellcentive.nosql.Configurator.init()
```

So now normal Hadoop `new Configuration()` construction (which is common inside `PythonRDD` infrastructure for Hadoop-based datasets) leads to all layers configuration loaded from class path where I can place configuration for needed cluster.

At least works for me.